# How to connect Microsoft Botframework to a database locally

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have started to build a Bot using Microsoft Botframework.I have two questions:

1.Can I connect Botframework to a SQL database locally? If yes ,how can it be done?

2.Can the Botframework update the database dynamically? Example: Reschedule today's meeting to wednesday. When the user quires, can the updated information be displayed to the user?

3.Does local database connection work after Deployment?

Answer (score 3):

Though I built my bot with Node.js, I think the procedure is quite similar.

I just connect to MSSQL Database directly using package mssql. For C#, you can see [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm).
  In my scenario, users can make some queries via my bot. First, you need to prepare all the connection strings. Upon receiving a request, my bot opens a new connection to the SQL DB and performs the query like

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase";     // C# code
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
```

Then it returns the result to your bot and you can return it to the user. The crucial thing is that you need to deal with the asynchronous task.

The answer to question 2 is also yes. Just change your query to `Update MyDatabase ...` and when the user submit a new query, the updated entry will be returned.

Comment: I know this is old, but could you share more about how you did this from node.js? I am trying to do the exact same thing, but cant use various functions because client js doesnt have the same functionality
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289683/how-to-get-data-from-sql-db-using-client-javascript