# How to get data from SQL DB using client JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, microsoft-teams

I am making a microsoft Teams app in javascript, and need to load data from an MS Sql database. Is there any way to get that data and display it in browser? I can do this for non web browser js using require, but havent found a way to get sql data into client js.

Comment: You mean , you want to access DB directly from client JS?

Comment: @Nish yes exactly

Comment: Is it possible you're doing this using -server side- Javascript (i.e. a Node app), rather than -client side- javascript running in a user's browser? Typically, for security and other reasons, direct access from a client's browser to SQL Server is a bad idea, and you should rather have an API in the middle